# Are IP range and IP block synonyms

Tags: ip

I would like to clarify if indeed IP range and IP block can be seen as synonyms?

Or perhaps they have a specialized use case?

For example, is IP range used when the intention is to talk about a CIDR range, while IP block used when referring to a contiguous block of IP numbers, regardless of if they can (or cannot) be represented as a CIDR (ie valid subnet)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitions can be very context dependent, but I'd say they are the opposite of what you said.  An IP block would (usually) refer to a group of addresses on a bit boundary (a CIDR block), while a range could be any group of contiguous addresses.  These kind of definitions can be imprecise, so in many cases, they could be synonymous.

Comment: In "spoken english", perhaps the person means the same thing. But you're technically correct (the best kind of correct!): 7-36 is a *range*, but it can't be written as a CIDR *block*.

Comment: All blocks are ranges, but not all ranges are blocks